# Java: First iteration of for loop takes longer

Tags: java, for-loop, midi, lag, synthesizer

I am writing some code to test using the MIDI libraries in Java, and have run across a problem. The pause between notes is much longer (almost twice as long, in fact) after the very first note than after all the others. I can't see any reason why, as the sequence of notes has already been generated (hence it is not also having to perform those calculations within the first iteration of the loop, it is only playing notes).

I think I may have also had this problem in the past with a simulation which, without any explanation I could find, took almost 100% of its tick length to perform calculations on the first tick only, and then used only about 2% on all successive iterations.

Main code (extract):

```
public void play() {
    MidiPlayer player = new MidiPlayer();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMNOTES; i++) {
        long tic = System.currentTimeMillis();
        player.playNote(10, notes[i]);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long toc = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(toc - tic);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code for playNote():

```
public void playNote(int channel, int note) {
    channels[channel].allNotesOff();
    channels[channel].noteOn(note + 60,  volume);
}
```

There are no 'if' statements that specify the first loop, so surely the delay should be uniform for all notes, as the number of calculations being performed should be the same for all iterations. Please note that the timing variables are just for testing purposes, and the effect was audibly noticeable before I included those.

EDIT: I should also mention that the output produced shows each iteration of the loop taking the expected 200 (occasionally 201) milliseconds. It seems to suggest that there is no gap - yet I clearly hear a gap every time I run the code.

Comment: Hard to say with the code exposed so far. I suspect the first `allNotesOff` invocation might be initializing *something* that takes time. Have you tried invoking it before starting to actually play, maybe joining the thread that invokes it?

Comment: I have just given this a go, and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: then maybe it's the first `noteOn` invocation... Like I said, it's hard to know what could go wrong without knowing what the `MidiPlayer` actually does. One thing to note is that `Thread.sleep` invocations are "subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers" (see API), which means your current thread might not always sleep for an accurate amount of time.

Comment: Or, it could be that your code runs fine, but the drivers used to actually talk to your MIDI receiver need some time to "warm up".

Comment: I have just tried shortening the delay from 200ms to 125ms, and have observed that there is a period later on which plays noticeably faster than the rest as well - something is wrong with the timing, but it seems to be consistent over running multiple times. And not just unique to the starting iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have sleeps, you should calculate how long you should sleep instead of trying to sleep the same amount of time each time - calculate how much more time you actually need to the next note to be played and sleep that much amount. i.e.

```
    long tic = System.currentTimeMillis();
    player.playNote(10, notes[i]);
    long time_spent = System.currentTimeMillis() - tic;
    Thread.sleep(200 - time_spent);
```